# How to handle model dependencies inside a Laravel package

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a Laravel package that is meant to be used across multiple Laravel projects. I need to use several Eloquent models within the package but since both the field names and class names might change depending on the consuming app, I am confused about the best way to handle these dependencies within my package.

Some background on the package: the different projects are all ecommerce sites and all have the same common elements such as Products and Orders but the database fields have different names and in some cases the Laravel models are namespaced differently or called different things. I am trying to build a package that can be used by all of these projects to analyze orders and detect potential fraud. Because some of the criteria we are using is checking things like whether or not the person who placed the account has previous order history and whether it was placed on an account, my package needs to have *some* way of accessing this data. So it needs access to things like an Order model (to check previous order history) and an Account model, but these things might vary depending on the consuming app.

The general API that I want is to be able to use a Fraud facade and have it *just work*, without requiring the consuming app to add a bunch of code wherever they use this package. Something like this:

```
$fraud = Fraud::checkOrder($order);
return Fraud::getFraudScore();
```

I am currently handling this by creating a large config file that informs my package what the name of needed models are in the consuming apps and what their field names are. It looks something like this:

```
'models' => [
    'order' => [
        'class' => 'App\Order',
        'id' => 'order_id',
        'name' => 'customer_name',
        ...
]
```

Then in my package class, I can just reference this like so:

```
protected $orderModel;

public function __construct($options = array())
{
    $this->orderModel = $options['models']['order'];
}

protected function findPreviousOrders()
{
    $order = $this->orderModel['class'];
    $previousOrders = $order::where($this->orderModel['name'], 'Bob')->get();
}
```

This *works* but doesn't feel very good to me. It requires a massive config file and doesn't make the code in my package extremely understandable unless you have an intimate knowledge of all the config options. I feel like there is something fundamental I am missing here in terms of model dependencies and package development, but I can't quite figure it out. Any thoughts on a better way to proceed? I'd prefer to require as *little code as possible* for the consuming apps to use this package.

Comment: Maybe if you split the configuration files it could help, besides you could use the global function to get config values and make your code more clear. I don't understand at all how your code works but those are two things that maybe could help

Comment: @Mirdrack the specific code implementation is less important than the general question of **how do you manage Eloquent dependencies when developing packages**. I'm building a package that will need knowledge of several Eloquent models of any Laravel project that uses it, but I don't know the best way to connect those models with my package. I'd like it to be usable without requiring the consuming app to pass in a bunch of arguments to a constructor every time it is called. I know I can restructure my config file but I'm curious if that's really the best way to handle this at all?

Comment: i would implement an php repository pattern and in some case create a service pattern. For example take a look at my Laravel E commerce package (How i have done it. i hope it gives you some starting point): https://github.com/avored/framework/tree/master/src/Models